# Why Mongoose adds my post object to the user's collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express, mongoose

I have such route for adding new post to the User Schema :

```
Router.route("/newpost").post(function(req, res) {
  UserSchema.findById(req.body.user).then((user) => {
    const id = function() {
      return (
        "_" +
        Math.random()
          .toString(36)
          .substr(2, 9)
      );
    };
    req.body.data.key = id();
    user.posts.unshift(req.body.data);
    user.save();
    res.send(user);
  });
});
```

This is my User's Schema :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name : {
        type: String
    },
    login : {
        type: String
    },
    posts : {
        type : Array
    },
    email : {
        type: String
    },
    password : {
        type: String
    },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("UserSchema", UserSchema, "users")
```

So, as you can see I am pushing my new post to the posts array for current user, but Mongodb also saves this post as empty object to the Users collection. Here what I get when I am pushing new post : 
[screenshot from the Robo 3T](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsqFk.png)

As you can see, new post added to the posts array, but also it appears as empty object below my user object.
How may I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: How do you know that the empty user document is the result of pushing a post?

Comment: I can't see anything inherently wrong with your code. Are you sure the `/newpost` route handler is only called once?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Check out screenshot in the post

Comment: @SamHolmes I think so... how may I check it?

Comment: Add a `console.log("logged", user)` right before you call `user.save()`, run the `POST` request _once_, and see what it says (and how many times it says it).

Comment: @SamHolmes Did it. It ran once.

Comment: What _exactly_ did it print out?

Comment: @SamHolmes
logged 
{ posts:
   [ { title: 'sdfsfdsdf', text: 'sdfsdfsdfsdfds', key: '_f32l6o55t' },
     { title: 'sdfsdfsd', text: 'sdfsdfsdf', key: '_6b4nnvacu' } ],
  _id: 5b4b1a916244bb7df4a2b370,
  login: 'root',
  name: 'root',
  email: 'root@root.com',
  password: '$2b$10$vaEUbFZfY1dzSka45lPWDuCof1rUZmpSWyDWygWdEL/p34pLMB3NK',
  __v: 1 }

Comment: That's so weird. And that definitely causes the extra null user to be inserted? Because provided that the ID is the same, there's no reason why that should happen.

Comment: @NikitaShchypylov: no, I see the empty object. What I'm asking is: how do you know WHAT inserted it? Maybe it was something else, not pushing a post to an existing user.

Comment: @SamHolmes yea, it is my first full-stack project, that's why I have plenty dummy errors :) It is probably forgotten semi-colon somewhere :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Because it is the only one route which causes this. Is there anyway to confirm it?

Comment: Sorry for double checking, but you're saying that when you delete the blank object, and do nothing else other than make a _single_ POST request to the route (as confirmed by the log above by only seeing the word "logged" _once_) _exactly_ as you're written above, it inserts a blank object _and_ updates the correct user properly?

Comment: Don't lose hope yet, I'm gonna be able to debug this properly in a few hours and try and see if I can replicate the behaviour.

Comment: This might be asking too much, so feel free to say no. But could I have a copy of the code as you have it currently with all secret keys or anything removed? I can't replicate this locally with the code given, which means it's gotta be happening elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @SamHolmes Hey, sorry for delay! Thanks you so much for your interest in this :)
1) Yes, I did it few seconds before and it works as you said (POSTed new post, it updates user and inserts blank one. I deleted this blank object, POSTed one more time and it inserted second post to my user, along with blank object)

Comment: @SamHolmes Sure, you are free to have a look on it in my [github repo](https://github.com/Nikulio/social). You will need only to paste your own mongoDB in the database file (server/database/db.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trawling through [your codebase](https://github.com/Nikulio/social), I think I've figured out what's happening and can point you in the right direction. I'm afraid I don't know enough about the structure of your react application to be able to offer a fix.

#### The issue is happening on the client, not the server

---

I sent the following two API requests to my local instance of your server using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/):

**`POST /api/add`**

```
{
    "name": "sam",
    "password": "example",
    "login": "samholmes",
    "email": "sam@sam.com"
}
```

*`response`*

```
{
    "_id" : "5b4cb4a3dcf25c13bdd05f80",
    "friends" : [],
    "requests" : [],
    "posts" : [],
    "name" : "sam",
    "password" : "$2b$10$G65S4St8OZWrhf0mSu3mduVyZRpycT5TMP3unM2GTdfOTXJaeChXK",
    "login" : "samholmes",
    "email" : "sam@sam.com",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

**`POST /api/newpost`**

```
{
    "user": "5b4cb4a3dcf25c13bdd05f80",
    "data": {
        "key": null,
        "title": "Example title",
        "text": "Example content"
    }
}
```

*`response`*

```
{
    "friends": [],
    "requests": [],
    "posts": [
        {
            "key": "_2utqr2k53",
            "title": "Example title",
            "text": "Example content"
        }
    ],
    "_id": "5b4cb4a3dcf25c13bdd05f80",
    "name": "sam",
    "password": "$2b$10$G65S4St8OZWrhf0mSu3mduVyZRpycT5TMP3unM2GTdfOTXJaeChXK",
    "login": "samholmes",
    "email": "sam@sam.com",
    "__v": 0
}
```

[image: Single item in Robo 3T]

As you can see, it only made a single user item and added the post to the `posts` array (as you'd expect). This means that there isn't a problem with the way the server handles requests, but instead that somewhere in the client it's sending the wrong requests.

---

Okay, so let's use the React application. After logging in, I type in the following details and hit the "Submit" button.

[image: React form]
[image: Submit result network requests]

Huh? Two network requests just went through. The one we want: `/newpost`, that updates the user with the new post correctly, but also this other `/add` request (which adds a new empty user and is causing the problem you're experiencing). Why does it send this?

I've dug around a bit, and it seems as though `smart/Feed/NewPost:42` is the culprit:

```
this.props.newPost(data, _id);
```

This causes React to call `handleSubmit` for both the API route you want and the one you don't.

---

I'm afraid I can't figure out any more right now about why this button causes two network requests, but hopefully it's enough to point you in the right direction!

Comment: Sam, if you ever will be in Kiev, DM me and I will buy you couple of beers! You are lifesaver :)
Yes, my old sagas `fetchPosts` was causing `yield put({ type: types.CREATE_USER_SUCCESS, user: user });` and that's why blank post was added. 

Once more, thanks you so much! I should more visit Network tab in Chrome. 

If you will ever need my help - let me know! See you!

Comment: Always wanted to visit Kiev ;-) So glad I could help, and AH that makes sense I _was_ wondering where it was occurring. Round after that's on me! Good luck with everything :-)

Comment: We are waiting for you then :) You too, pal!